# Why does my donation board dont work anymore?

Tags: lua, roblox

I used a template from IcyDeluxeDev called "DonoBoard". I just changed the colors, product id (changed to mine) and moved the board to a different place. After this, it no longer works. When I put the model back but at the spawning point it works but if I move it elsewhere then no longer. Anyone here to help me?

I also change the place of the first-place character (but I don't think this is the reason why my dono board no longer works).

Comment: Do more debugging, "It's not working" is not helpful. Figure out what is not working and provide a minimal example.